# how to use matlab to select microcontroller for the implementation (in hardware) of a script

Tags: matlab, microcontroller

I have a script that I will eventually insert inside a microcontroller and I would like to know if there is anything I can do in Matlab in order to get info to choose an adecuate microcontroller (clock speed or MIPS, SRAM, etc).
I did the following in order to get an estimation of running time in a target microcontroller at 40 MIPS:

```
t=10;%running time of my script in one thread using: LASTN = maxNumCompThreads(1);
cs=3500;%MHz. clock speed or frequency at which the script run
mips=cs*1e6;%estimation of my cpu MIPS
flops=t*mips;%estimation of how many operation where done in those 10s
target_p=40*1e6;%target MIPS
target_t=flops/target_p;
target_t_min=target_t/60
```

So, if this calculation is correct, my 10s script will take 14min to run in a microcontroller at 40 MIPS...
Is this correct? If not, what can I do?

Comment: I maybe a bit out of touch, but what microcontroller can run Matlab inside it?

Comment: none, I will adapt the script to C++ first

Comment: I'm confused. If you are going to adapt the script to C++, shouldn't you be measuring the execution time of the adaptation as a means of estimating the amount of compute resources you need? Otherwise, there doesn't seem to be reasonable basis for comparison between a Matlab script and some C++ code.

Comment: true, but the adaptation will require time, and I need some approximation at least for the time being...